# Is Rails now working with Ruby 1.9?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to run Ruby on Rails with Ruby 1.9x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783651/is-it-possible-to-run-ruby-on-rails-with-ruby-1-9x)

Browsing the web says that Rails is not compatible with Ruby 1.9 but I would like to know if it's always the case?

And how long should we wait to see a Rails version working with Ruby 1.9? Is it work in progress? In dev stage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, the latest Rails works fully with Ruby 1.9.1.**

Issues you have will be around gems/plugins that might not be compatible yet. But more and more of the popular gems/plugins are now working with 1.9. (As pointed out in Rahul's link.) See [isitRuby19.com](http://www.isitRuby19.com) for compatibility info.

The other aspect is that if you're developing on Windows, there isn't a one-click installer for Ruby 1.9 yet, so getting set up locally might be more of a pain than it's worth.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps:

[Rails 2.3 with Ruby 1.9](http://blog.nextlogic.net/2009/05/rails-23-with-ruby-19.html)

Comment: It does for me. (http://blog.nextlogic.net/2009/05/rails-23-with-ruby-19.html).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found this link:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/2_3_release_notes.html

Indeed, **rails 2.3 works with ruby 1.9**. That's cool!

Answer (score 0):

yes, but you are gonna have a lo of troubles with the plugins